# Is there a way in converse to force users to set a nickname on joining the room?

Tags: converse.js

Exactly as stated above - I want users to be forced to set a nickname on entering each room. Is there any way to set this/ can I just force it through javascript to always prompt on joining a room?

- I have tried setting it by hand, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected
- I can sometimes force it, but my JS experience isn't good enough.

Comment: Make sure that `auto_register_muc_nickname` is set to `false`.